# Firebase querying: how to return all keys for a given value in a nested dictionary?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsdictionary, nosql

[Here's the full tree,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RLFp.png) but below I have included a simple version as well.

```
Survey:   
     DaysAvail:
          Mon:
              uid1  
              uid2  
          Tues: 
              ....
     FitnessLevel
          Beginner: 
              uid1
```

What I want to do is return search for uid and return all the parents. So, 
searching by uid1 I want to return Monday, Beginner. How can I do this? Here is my current code, but it returns all the uids for a given nested value, like "beginner" "Monday", and so forth, which is inefficient and requires a lot of repeated code.

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("Survey").observe(.value, with: {
        snapshot in

            for childSnap in snapshot.children.allObjects {

                let snap = childSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot

                if let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary,
let snapVal = snapshotValue[snap.key] as? NSDictionary {  

let daysofWeek = snapshotValue.object(forKey: "DaysAvail") as! NSDictionary


let availMonday = daysofWeek["Monday"] as! NSDictionary

let mondayUID = availMonday.allKeys
```

The value of availMonday is:

```
{
    2x4hC66p3YYM5wTiXJINP5Hz0PK2 = 1;
    LuA7dLLD4iPSkV5GNWJMEogAmwg1 = 1;
    QEpyq9KRkrcoePkvQkJEnVOKxyE3 = 1;
}
```

The value of mondayUID is :

```
[2x4hC66p3YYM5wTiXJINP5Hz0PK2, LuA7dLLD4iPSkV5GNWJMEogAmwg1,   
QEpyq9KRkrcoePkvQkJEnVOKxyE3]
```

Any feedback or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't do this - your structure is too deep. You should [denormalize](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) your data or change the structure to allow you do perform the query. Also what would differentiate uid1 returning Beginner vs uid returning Mon:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Restructure the database**

Since you have the value of uid already, it would be best to use the following database structure:

```
DaysAvail:
      uid1: Monday  
      uid2: Tuesday
      uid3: Friday
```

**2. Make a more specific call to Firebase**

With the above structure, you can perform the call in O(1) time

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().databaseRef.child("DaysAvail").child(uid1).observe(.value, with: {
    snapshot in
})
```

**3. Use Firebase Queries where needed**

Checkout [Firebase Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data). With the above structure you can still retrieve all uids that are available on a particular day. For example, you would still be able to retrieve all uids that are available on Monday.